# YAML read should be an Hash not an Array, what's wrong?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am reading a YAML file:

```
listing = YAML.load_file(File.expand_path(....)
```

I try to iterate on the listing items on build an OpenStructure

```
items = Array.new
listing.each do |item|
  items << OpenStruct.new(item)
end
```

But it's raising an error:

```
undefined method `each_pair' for ["item1", "label1"]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

My test YAML file is:

```
item1: label1
item2: label2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the content.. Yaml can be a hash or array of hash too.

Comment: Just use `items = []` instead of `items = Array.new`. It's more idiomatic in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occuring in the [`OpenStruct` initializer](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html#method-c-new).

When you call `Hash#each` and give it a block with arity = 1, the block gets an array like `[key, value]`. Then you're passing that to `OpenStruct.new`, which results in an error since you can't initialize an `OpenStruct` with an `Array`.

What I *think* you want is:

```
listing.each do |key, value|
  items << OpenStruct.new({ key: value })
end
```

alternatively, the yaml file could be

```
- item1: label1
- item2: label2
```

and I believe the code would work as is.

The YAML file you have is deserialized to:

```
{ item1: "label1", item2: "label2" }
```

whereas the one I've described would be:

```
[{ item1: "label1" }, { item2: "label2" }]
```

Comment: thanks , you're right, updating the yaml file did the trick ... +1